# Cannot convert List object to List<clasname>

Tags: java, api

Cannot convert from List to List
When trying to use a list in my Test method, I am getting an error with adding a list to an ArrayList.
This is the code that the error is in:

```
    @Test
public void testGetAllModules_OK() throws Exception {
List<Modules> modules = Arrays.asList(new Modules(1, "C02103", "Architecture", 1, true));
when(modRepo.findAll()).thenReturn(modules);
mockMvc.perform(get("/Modules"))
.andExpect(status().isOk())
.andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].ModuleCode", is ("C02103")))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].title", is ("Architecture")))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.[0].semester", is (1)))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].CoreModule", is(true)));

verify(modRepo, times(1)).findAll();
}
```

Here is the creation of Module class

```
@Entity
public class Modules implements Iterable<Modules> {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int ModuleId;
private String ModuleCode;
private String title;
private int semester;
private boolean CoreModule;
ArrayList<String> lecture = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> mod = new ArrayList<String>();

public Modules(int ModuleId, String ModuleCode, String title, int semester, boolean CoreModule) {
    this.ModuleId = ModuleId;
    this.ModuleCode = ModuleCode;
    this.title = title;
    this.semester = semester;
    this.CoreModule = CoreModule;
}
public Modules(String ModuleCode, String title, int semester, boolean CoreModule)
{
    this.ModuleCode = ModuleCode;
    this.title = title;
    this.semester = semester;
    this.CoreModule = CoreModule;
}
public Modules(String ModuleCode,String title, boolean CoreModule )
{
    this.ModuleCode = ModuleCode;
    this.title = title;
    this.CoreModule = CoreModule;
}
public Modules()
{}

/*
 * @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
 * 
 * @OneToMany(mappedBy = "module", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade =
 * CascadeType.ALL)
 */
public int getModuleId() {
    return ModuleId;
}
public void setModuleId(int moduleId) {
    ModuleId = moduleId;
}
public String getModuleCode() {
    return ModuleCode;
}
public void setModuleCode(String moduleCode) {
    ModuleCode = moduleCode;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public int getSemester() {
    return semester;
}
public void setSemester(int semester) {
    this.semester = semester;
}
public boolean isCoreModule() {
    return CoreModule;
}
public void setCoreModule(boolean coreModule) {
    CoreModule = coreModule;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Modules [ModuleId=" + ModuleId + ", ModuleCode=" + ModuleCode + ", title=" + title + ", semester="
            + semester + ", CoreModule=" + CoreModule + "]";
}
```

}
Any help would be very appreciated, as I'm getting the same error with similar test methods

Comment: Please EDIT your question to give the exact compilation error message, and say exactly which line it occurs on.  (Your said: *" I am getting an error with adding a list to an ArrayList ..."* but that code isn't adding anything to anything, as far as I can see.)